# Loop through a directory unix shell programming

Tags: bash, unix

Use a for loop to go through the filenames in the directory. In this version, only loop through the filenames that do not have a ".old" extension

Inside the loop, rename the file to the new name.

Comment: That reads an awful lot like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming access to bash 4+ (check with `bash --version`) this can be done with a two-liner:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in !(*.old); do mv -- "$f" new_"$f"; done
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace what's between **`do`** and **`done`** this is an example of how you can use **`$f`**

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /data
list=`ls -rt`

for f in $list
do
    c=`grep -c or=90 $f`
    if [ "$c" -gt "0" ]; then    
        echo "file is $f and it has $c"
    fi
done

cd -
```

Comment: This will break for any filenames with spaces, since `for` splits on spaces by default; and for filenames containing newlines, since `ls` splits on newlines.

Answer (score -1):

As this isn't a homework question, and you just want to know the best way to do this, here is a way to do it with find:

```
find /startfolder -not -name '*.old' -exec mv {} newname_{} \;
```

This will get all files that don't have the suffix 'old' and rename them with the prefix newname_

No for loop required.

Answer (score -1):

```
for filename in $(ls $1)
do
        echo $filename | grep "\.old$" > /dev/null
                if [ $? != 0 ]
                then
                        mv $1/$filename $1/$filename.old
                fi
done
```